# Heroku env variables are the same on staging and production when using pipelines

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I am using React and Node.  When I push to master branch it automatically deploys to Heroku staging app, and then if everything is ok I promote to production. The problem is when I have some env variables with the same name but different value. I set those env variables in Heroku settings. When I push to staging that env variable is used but when I promote staging to production, value of env variable that was set on staging Heroku app is also used in production. That is because Heroku doesnt build app again when I promote.

How do I resolve this? I saw mention some Release Phase and that will get env variables again when promote but don't know how to configure it.

Comment: I ran into this same problem unwittingly using Next.js and the new NEXT_PUBLIC_ environment variable prefix, which actually compiles any usages of the variable to hard-coded inline values in your js bundle at build time! (Not exactly an environment variable anymore is it?)

Answer (score 2):

This means your app is storing its environment variables on disk at build time to use them afterwards.
I suppose it does that when precompiling your assets.

You only have 2 solutions here.
The first one is to stop using Heroku Pipelines and always rebuild your app whenever you deploy again.

The second one is to rearchitect the way you use config variables in your app.
If you need those values on the frontend, you could specify an endpoint which retrieves them, reading straight from `process.env`.

The second solution is probably better. Your config variables are meant to be changed without the need to rebuild your app (whenever you do `heroku config:set`).

Comment: Thanks Damien. Can you please write me how the second solution would be implemented to read straight from process.env. Not quiet sure what you mean by that. I use axios on the frontend.

Comment: Sorry, my nodejs knowledge is very low, and I don't know axios at all. `process.env` will allow you to read an environment variable at runtime though. You need to always read those environment variables, and not store them on disk.

Comment: In Next.js you can use [Runtime Configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration) to solve this problem and pass environment variables to the client through publicRuntimeConfig.